# Visual Basic code to Select and Delete filtered rows of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro in an Excel workbook and pulled this code from VBA. The line Rows("45:45").Select does not work well as the filtered rows will vary each time I run the report. I am total novice when it comes to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Chloe", "Bob", "GBUK", "Shape", "Lifestyle", "MYP", _
    "MYP Aus", "MYP In", "MYP Retail", "MYV", "MYV Retail"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Rows("45:45").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

Thanks
Laura

EDITED:

I have edited the code as follows;

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Chloe", "Bob", "GBUK", "Shape", "Lifestyle", "MYP", _
    "MYP Aus", "MYP In", "MYP Retail", "MYV", "MYV Retail"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Rows(rowVariable).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

I am receiving a runtime error when I run the macro.

I have also removed `.Select` but I receive a Compile Error: invalid use of property.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Stop using `.Select` and `Selection` it makes your code slow and unreliable.

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect your code to do? It is not clear.

Comment: I am trying to filter the data to remove rows that belong to a set criteria.  I have built the macro by recording the macro in Excel and performing the steps.  The next time I run the report, the rows will be different, which is why I need to change the code to reflect that but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

1. Filter your data
2. Don't use `.Select`
3. Exclude the header row if there is one
4. Get all visible cells of the `UsedRange` (without the header)
5. Delete them
6. Remove the filter

And you end up with something like

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteFilteredData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define the sheet you want to work with
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Filter
    ws.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Chloe", "Bob", "GBUK", "Shape", "Lifestyle", "MYP", _
        "MYP Aus", "MYP In", "MYP Retail", "MYV", "MYV Retail"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    ' get filtered data without heading
    Dim FilteredRows As Range
    On Error Resume Next  ' avoid an error message if no rows were filtered
    Set FilteredRows = ws.UsedRange.Resize(RowSize:=ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(RowOffset:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ' if you don't have a header row use
    'Set FilteredRows = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0  ' re-activate error reporting !!!
    
    If Not FilteredRows Is Nothing Then
        FilteredRows.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to delete", vbInformation
    End If
    
    ws.Range("$A:$AQ").AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rows("45:45").Select`
can be changed to
`Rows(rowVariable & ":" & rowVariable)`

Where row variable is a variable which can change at run time.

Comment: If start row and end row is the same as in "45:45" you can just write `Rows(45)` or `Rows(rowVariable)`. No need for `rowVariable & ":" & rowVariable`.